# How can I create pkcs7 with rsassa_pss in python?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I need to sign a file using the RSASSA-PSS signing algorithm and, as a result, create a PKCS7 Signature. However, the `cryptography`  module doesn't seem to have such an option. Is there any way to do it?

```
from pathlib import Path
from asn1crypto import cms
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import load_key_and_certificates

pfx_password ='insert_pwd'
pfx = Path('insert_p12_name.p12').read_bytes()
private_key, cert, add_certs = load_key_and_certificates(pfx, pfx_password.encode('utf-8'), None)

sign_filepath: str = 'insert_file_name'
with open(sign_filepath, 'rb') as f:
    sign_bytes: bytes = f.read()
    f.close()
    
options = [pkcs7.PKCS7Options.DetachedSignature]
p7s_bytes = pkcs7.PKCS7SignatureBuilder().set_data(sign_bytes).add_signer(
   cert, private_key, hashes.SHA256()
).sign(
    serialization.Encoding.DER, options
)

cert_chain = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(p7s_bytes)
content_info: cms.ContentInfo = cms.ContentInfo.load(p7s_bytes)
signer_info: cms.SignedData = content_info['content']['signer_infos'][0]
signature_algorithm = signer_info['signature_algorithm']['algorithm'].native
print(signature_algorithm)
```

Output is `sha256_rsa`. How to change it to 'rsassa_pss'?